# How to add shadow and perfect task bar operation with Qt application with no frame

Tags: qt, qt4

I use the following code to implement a window on Windows7 with no frame and title bar:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

and I continue to deal with the mouse event to make it can drag to move.
But there is still some problems puzzled me:

1. When I click the task bar icon, the app can not minimize or restore like other apps.
2. Window has no shadow

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: on what platform? If on windows, then it is normal behaviour. Frameless windows have no shadows on Windows.

Comment: yeah, it's on windows. I want to remove the default title bar, but don't want to disable the shadow, is there any methods to fix it?

Comment: As I told you frameless windows have no shadows on Windows platform

Answer (score 1):

Shadows on frameless windows is possible to add with [DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Though it seems to be a problem with translucent frameless windows.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

extern "C"
{
    typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *t_DwmSetWindowAttribute)(HWND hwnd, DWORD dwAttribute, LPCVOID pvAttribute, DWORD cbAttribute);
    typedef HRESULT (WINAPI *t_DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea)(HWND hwnd, const MARGINS *pMarInset);
}

void DwmSetWindowAttribute(HWND hwnd, DWORD dwAttribute, LPCVOID pvAttribute, DWORD cbAttribute)
{
    HMODULE shell;
    shell = LoadLibrary(L"dwmapi.dll");
    if(shell){
        t_DwmSetWindowAttribute set_window_attribute = reinterpret_cast<t_DwmSetWindowAttribute>(GetProcAddress (shell, "DwmSetWindowAttribute"));
        set_window_attribute(hwnd, dwAttribute, pvAttribute, cbAttribute);

        FreeLibrary (shell);
    }
}

void DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(HWND hwnd, const MARGINS *pMarInset){
    HMODULE shell;
    shell = LoadLibrary(L"dwmapi.dll");
    if(shell){
        t_DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea extend_frame_into_client_area = reinterpret_cast<t_DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea>(GetProcAddress(shell, "DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea"));
        extend_frame_into_client_area(hwnd, pMarInset);

        FreeLibrary(shell);
    }
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY ncrp = DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
    DwmSetWindowAttribute((HWND)this->winId(), DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &ncrp, sizeof(ncrp));
    const MARGINS margins = {-1, -1, -1, -1};
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea((HWND)this->winId(), &margins);
}
```